# Does Pyramid have a Signal/Slot system

Tags: python, signals, pylons, pyramid

Django happens to have a [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/signals/) system built in and it would be quite useful for a project I'm working on.

I've been reading though the Pyramid docs and it does appear to have an [Events](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/events.html) system which is tied very closely to Signals, but not quite. Would something like this work for a general purpose signal system or should I roll my own?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The events system used by Pyramid fulfils the exact same use-cases as the Signals system. Your application can define arbitrary events and attach subscribers to them.

To create a new event, define an interface for it:

```py
from zope.interface import (
    Attribute,
    Interface,
    )

class IMyOwnEvent(Interface):
    foo = Attribute('The foo value')
    bar = Attribute('The bar value')
```

You then define an actual implementation of the event:

```py
from zope.interface import implementer

@implementer(IMyOwnEvent)
class MyOwnEvent(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
```

The interface is actually optional, but helps documentation and makes it easier to provide multiple implementations. So you could get away with omitting the interface definition and `@implementer` parts altogether.

Wherever you want to signal this event, use the `registry.notify` method; here I assume you have a request available to reach the registry:

```py
request.registry.notify(MyOwnEvent(foo, bar))
```

This'll send the request to any subscribers you've registered; either with `config.add_subscriper` or with `pyramid.events.subscriber`:

```py
from pyramid.events import subscriber
from mymodule.events import MyOwnEvent

@subscriber(MyOwnEvent)
def owneventsubscriber(event):
    event.foo.spam = 'eggs'
```

You can also use the `IMyOwnEvent` interface instead of the `MyOwnEvent` class and your subscriber will be notified of all events that implement the interface, not just your specific implementation of that event.

Note that notifying subscribers never catches exceptions (like `send_robust` in Django would do).